# Updating Profiles into All Subcribers from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, attribute

I am currently needing to update one of my attributes in All Subscribers with the same attribute that currently lives in one of Master Data Extensions. I have created the attribute in All Subs but don't know how to go about refreshing or duplicating that data into its attribute in All Subs.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Did this work for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

1. Extract the master DE  using a [data extract activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/)
2. Transfer it into the export folder in your FTP using a [file transfer activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/).
3. Transfer it to in the import folder using another file transfer activity.
4. Import it back into the all subscriber list using an [import activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/).

If this is a an activity you want to repeat, you can configure an automation to include all these steps in [Automation Studio](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/)

Another option would to copy the file from the FTP location on your computer and import it from there. This negates the need for the second file transfer activity.

Comment: +1 Data_Kid. You can also do this manually by extracting the data to the FTP, saving to your PC/desktop, and importing manually. Slightly less steps if you don't have the File Locations and Transfer Activities set up.

Comment: @CameronRobert good point! Will update answer

Comment: @CameronRobert better late than never